# How to disable resizing animation in Recharts when keeping loading animation enabled?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Area#isAnimationActive disables both animation which runs when preparing chart and resizing animation.
I need to keep initial animation on and turn off resizing animation is it possible?
"recharts": "1.6.2"